# checking if a value is contained in any columns sql

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have a number, say 12345. I also have a table. I need to check if the number is contained in any column of the table. I need to use SQL. How can I do this ? The table has many columns. Thank you!  ( I am a complete novice to SQL)

Comment: Does this help? [How to check if a value exists in any of the columns in a table in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995781/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-any-of-the-columns-in-a-table-in-sql)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And are you looking to match exact column contents or also if it is contained as part of a string?

Comment: thanks, I need an exact match.

Comment: You're supposed to know which column you store your values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure SQL, there is no easy solution to search in all columns at once. You do need to write down all the column names.

If you are looking for an exact match, `IN` can help shortening the syntax a little:

```
select *
from mytable
where 12345 in (col1, col2, col3, ...)
                                 --^-- do list all remaining columns here
```